# Update/modify object retrieved from dojo datastore/JsonRestStore

Tags: javascript, rest, dojo

I'm using a DOJO JsonRestStore. I modify fields in the object.

What would be the proper procedure for persisting the modified object back to the datastore and REST service?

Update: Removed info about grid as it was not part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I had assumed that the returned item would be synchronized with the datastore. It doesn't appear so and must be updated manually using:

```
store.setValue(item, field, value);
```

I was also hoping for a command equivalent to JPA merge. If you overwrite the prior object with:

```
store.newItem( updatedVersionOfItem );
```

and the item has the same unique id, it will overwrite the old item similar to merge.

Does anyone know if there some sort of a factory that will create getters and setters for an item that will call store.setValue() for each field?

I imagine it would be something like the following:

```
var wrappedItem = itemWrapperFactory.createWrapper( item, store );
...
//Some where in createWrapper(...), this is just the concept
for (var itemField in itemFieldList)
this.__defineGetter__( itemField[index] , function(val){
    store.setValue(item, itemField[index], val);      
});
```

I am consider writing my own as its a neat piece of architecture.

Comment: If you are using a dojox.data.JsonRestore and a dojox.grid.DataGrid, if you've setup the grid property "store" to be your JRS, and set your cells as editable... changes SHOULD definitly be reflected to the store when you update properties from the grid... Do you have something else inbetween ?

Comment: Right. I wasn't updating them from the grid, I was just retrieving them using info I got from the grid. That was one source of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, a store.save() should be enough... If not, it means you have a problem between your grid and the store.

Comment: Your probably right about something being wrong. I fetched an item using fetchitembyid(), modified it, called store.save() and it didn't persist back to the service. isDirty() is false after I modify the object.